# How do Nice Answer badges work?

Tags: support, badges

What is the rule for nice answer badges? I have 2 answers with 10 upvotes, but I only received only one nice answer badge.

What happened?

Comment: I see 2 nice answer badges on your profile...

Comment: I see 3 nice answer badges on your SO profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice answer badge is awarded (sometimes there is a delay) when a question receives a score of +10.

It should be noted that if you receive a Nice Answer badge, you will not lose the badge even if the answer happens to drop below +10 sometime in the future. BUT, if it did drop down and another item goes to +10, you will not receive a new badge for that item (your badge count will remain the same because it will go back to matching you current totals).

Comment: I thought it was "10 upvotes" not "+10."  Note the distinction.  Under one, you could potentially have a negative answer that qualified as a "nice answer."  Course, I could be wrong, but if so, the badge description needs refining.

Comment: I'm almost certain it is +10, not just ten upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The badges can take a little while (usually of the order of minutes) to come through. It all depends on the timing of when the procedures are run that calculate what badge criteria have been met.

Jeff could tell you how frequently they are run, but I suspect that he would like to keep it quiet.