# what is the mean for badges nice answer: Answer score of 10 or more

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do Nice Answer badges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8046/how-do-nice-answer-badges-work)

what is the mean for badges nice answer: Answer score of 10 or more

an answer has score 10 or more ?

or

all answers of an user posted have 10  or more score in total?

Comment: You might find this helpful: [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a single answer scoring 10 or more to have this badge.

Duplicate : [How do Nice Answer badges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8046/how-do-nice-answer-badges-work)